# Trying to Deploy django + wsgi + apache + windows

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a django server but I even reinstall all but I got the same error in apache and I do not know how to make it Works, I hope you can help me because it makes me crazy.

Wsgi is installed correctly, it works fine with runserver command but not with apache.

httpd.conf

```
LoadFile "c:/users/srvpc/appdata/local/programs/python/python35/python35.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/srvpc/appdata/local/programs/python/python35/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/srvpc/appdata/local/programs/python/python35"



WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\abaa\proyecto\proyecto\wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:\abaa\proyecto"

<Directory "C:\abaa\proyecto">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


Alias /static "C:\abaa\proyecto\aplicacion\static"

<Directory "C:\abaa\proyecto\aplicacion\static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

apache access log:

```
192.168.1.216 - - [18/Feb/2019:10:57:58 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 530
```

apache error log:

```
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::c109:4f13:c7f3:c19b. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:53.985985 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1800:tid 540] AH00455: Apache/2.4.38 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.5.24 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:53.985985 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1800:tid 540] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jan 18 2019 14:26:34
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:53.985985 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1800:tid 540] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:53.985985 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1800:tid 540] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1824
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::c109:4f13:c7f3:c19b. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::c109:4f13:c7f3:c19b. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:54.236011 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1824:tid 556] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:59.017764 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1824:tid 1108] [client 192.168.1.216:49423] mod_wsgi (pid=1824): Target WSGI script 'C:/abaa/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:59.017764 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1824:tid 1108] [client 192.168.1.216:49423] mod_wsgi (pid=1824): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/abaa/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:59.017764 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1824:tid 1108] [client 192.168.1.216:49423] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:59.017764 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1824:tid 1108] [client 192.168.1.216:49423]   File "C:/abaa/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:59.017764 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1824:tid 1108] [client 192.168.1.216:49423]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r
[Mon Feb 18 10:57:59.017764 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1824:tid 1108] [client 192.168.1.216:49423] ImportError: No module named 'django'\r
```

Comment: It's telling you it can't find Django. How did you install it? Did you just a virtualenv?

Comment: yes I just install by pip install virtualenv, pip install virtualenvwrapper-win, virtualenv abaa, then I enter Venv and pip install django

Comment: You need to point mod_wsgi to the virtualenv, then. See [the docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#embedded-mode-single-application).

Comment: I already try it, thank you any way!

Answer (score 0):

`WSGIPythonHome` should **not** be the directory of the system Python installation, but of your **virtual environment's path** (e.g. the location where you can find `Lib`, `Scripts` etc and, inside `Lib\site-packages` can find `django`).

Change this:

```
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/srvpc/appdata/local/programs/python/python35"
```

To:

```
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/srvpc/Envs/yourenv"
```

assuming, of course, that your virtual environment is in `c:/users/srvpc/Envs/yourenv`.